# angularjs bootstrap carousel dynamically adding sliders after image loads causing duplicate error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a carousel which looks like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron-carousel" carousel interval="controller.jumbotronInterval" no-pause="true" no-transition="true">
    <div class="slide" slide ng-repeat="slide in controller.jumbotron" active="slide.active" style="background-image: url({{ slide.image }});">

    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller looks like this (simplified for brevity)

```
.controller('HomeController', ['preloader', function (preloader) {
    var self = this;

    // Set up our main carousel
    self.jumbotronInterval = 2000;
    self.jumbotron = [];

    // Private function to create the main slider slides
    var createSlides = function () {

        // Create an array of our images
        var slides = [{
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_MG_0629.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_J5Y6128.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_J5Y6588.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_J5Y6779.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_J5Y6929.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_J5Y7157.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_J5Y7286.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_MG_0151.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_MG_0337.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_MG_0417.jpg'
        }, {
            image: '/assets/images/carousel/jumbotron/_MG_1300.jpg'
        }];

        // For each slide
        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

            // Get our slide
            var slide = slides[i];

            // If our image has loaded
            preloader(slide.image).then(function () {

                // Add to our jumbotron
                self.jumbotron.push(slide);

                console.log(self.jumbotron);
            });
        }
    };

    // Create your slides
    createSlides();
}]);
```

So basically what is happening is my preloader service waits until an image has loaded and then pushes the slider to my array.
This is what my service looks like (pretty simple):

```
.factory('preloader', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return function (url) {

        // Create our deferred promise and create an image object
        var deffered = $q.defer(),
            image = new Image();

        // Assign the url to the image
        image.src = url;

        // If the image has finished loading
        if (image.complete) {

            // Resolve the promise
            deffered.resolve();

            // Otherwise it hasn't completed
        } else {

            // Add an event listener to the load event
            image.addEventListener('load', function () {

                // Resolve the promise when the image loads
                deffered.resolve();
            });

            // Add an event listener to the load event
            image.addEventListener('error', function () {

                // Reject the promise
                deffered.reject();
            });
        }

        // Return our promise
        return deffered.promise;
    }
}])
```

The problem is that when it pushes the slide to the slides array I get an error in angular:

> > Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

I did a console log after every image load had completed and that is when the application complains.
I "could" wait until all the images have loaded, but I would prefer to add them sequentially.
Does anyone know how I can do this?